# PostgreSQL - query empty string fields

Tags: postgis, imposm

I'm loading OpenStreetMap data into a PostGIS database with Imposm3.

Regarding the documentation [Documentation](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/mapping.html#column-types), fields with NULL are stored as empty field.

To query attributes who are not empty I try:

```
SELECT * FROM table.polygon WHERE 'attribute' is not ''
```

Unfortunately, this is not working.

How do I exclude empty string fields as query in a PostGIS database?

Comment: You have a major errors in your SQL. `where 'attribute' is not ''` means "where string that I write manually to be "attribute" is not an empty string". Close the name of the attribute between double quotes or leave it unqueted. For example this Works `select * from table.polygon where attribute not like ''`. Your question deals with pure SQL without any GIS connection.

Comment: As this is a pure SQL issue, not a GIS-centric one, so you might find [dba.se] a better resource on SQL language use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three issues in the one query:

- `table.polygon` implies a reference to a column in table; the proper syntax for the table in a FROM clause would be `schemaname.tablename`
- Your WHERE clause compares a literal string containing the characters "a-t-t-r-i-b-u-t-e" with a literal empty string (which would not ever succeed), and
- Using the 'is not' construct restricted to the clause IS NOT NULL instead of a comparison operator.

So the corrected query would resemble:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   schemaname.tablename
WHERE  attributename <> ''
```

Alternates (but less canonical forms) on the WHERE clause could include:

```
WHERE  attributename != ''
```

```
WHERE  NOT attributename = ''
```

```
WHERE  attributename NOT IN ('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select * from table.polygon where 'attribute' != ''
```

instead of is not

Comment: This would return all rows, since the literals are not equal.